# Exercise 6, Section 23 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, connectedness

> Let $A\subset X$. Show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$ and $X-A$ , then $C$ intersects $\operatorname{Bd}A$.

**My attempt:**

**Approach(1):** Assume towards contradiction, $C\cap \partial A=\emptyset$. By definition of interior, $ A^{\circ}, (X-A)^\circ \in \mathcal{T}_X$. So $C\cap A^\circ, C\cap (X-A)^\circ \in \mathcal{T}_C$. Since $\emptyset \neq A\cap C\subseteq \overline{A}\cap C$, we have $\overline{A}\cap C \neq \emptyset$. By [Exercise 19, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351745/861687), $\overline{A}\cap C=(A^\circ \cup \partial A) \cap C=(C\cap A^\circ)\cup (C\cap \partial A)=(C \cap A^\circ)\cup \emptyset=C \cap A^\circ$. So $C \cap A^\circ \neq \emptyset$. Since $\emptyset \neq (X-A)\cap C\subseteq \overline{X-A}\cap C$, we have $\overline{X-A}\cap C \neq \emptyset$. By exercise 19 section 17, $C\cap \overline{X-A}=C\cap ((X-A)^\circ \cup \partial(X-A))= C\cap ((X-A)^\circ \cup \partial A)= C\cap (X-A)^\circ$. So $C\cap (X-A)^\circ \neq \emptyset$. By elementary set theory, $(C\cap A^\circ) \cap (C\cap (X-A)^\circ)= C\cap (A^\circ \cap (X-A)^\circ)=C\cap \emptyset =\emptyset$. By distributive law, $(C\cap A^\circ) \cup (C\cap (X-A)^\circ)= C \cap (A^\circ \cup (X-A)^\circ)$. Since [$X =\operatorname{int}(A) \sqcup \operatorname{int}(X\setminus A) \sqcup \partial (A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4440200/861687), we have $C=C\cap X= C\cap (A^\circ \cup (X-A)^\circ \cup \partial A)= [C\cap (A^\circ \cup (X-A)^\circ)]\cup (C\cap \partial A)= C\cap (A^\circ \cup (X-A)^\circ)$. So $(C\cap A^\circ) \cup (C\cap (X-A)^\circ)= C \cap (A^\circ \cup (X-A)^\circ)=C$. Hence $C\cap A^\circ$ and $C\cap (X-A)^\circ$ form separation of $C$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $C$ is connected. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(2):** Assume towards contradiction, $C\cap \partial A=\emptyset$. By definition of closure, $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{X-A}$ are closed in $X$. By theorem 17.2, $C\cap \overline{A}$ and $C\cap \overline{X-A}$ are closed in $C$. Since $C\cap A, C\cap (X-A)\neq \emptyset$, we have $C\cap \overline{A}, C\cap \overline{X-A}\neq \emptyset$. By definition of boundary,$\emptyset =C\cap \partial A = (C\cap \overline{A})\cap (C\cap \overline{X-A})$. By [Exercise 19, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351745/861687), $(C\cap \overline{A})\cup (C\cap \overline{X-A})$$=C\cap (\overline{A}\cup \overline{X-A})$$= C\cap (A^\circ \cup \partial A \cup X-A^\circ)$$=C \cap (X\cup \partial A)$$= C\cup \emptyset=C$. Hence $C\cap \overline{A}$ and $C\cap \overline{X-A}$ form separation of $C$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $C$ is connected. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: IMO, approach(2) is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) looks fine. It might be a bit more efficient to use $A^\circ$ and $(A^c)^\circ$ to partition $C$, where $A^c$ means $X\setminus A$. These are clearly disjoint open sets.

In detail: it's not difficult to see from definition that $X=A^\circ\sqcup(A^c)^\circ\sqcup\partial A$ for any $A\subseteq X$ ($\sqcup$ means disjoint union), and also $\partial A^c=\partial A$, $A\subseteq A^\circ\sqcup\partial A$, $A^c\subseteq (A^c)^\circ\sqcup\partial A$. Suppose $C$ does not intersect $\partial A$ and yet intersect $A$, then it has to intersect $A^\circ$. Similarly for $A^c$. Then $A^\circ$ and $(A^c)^\circ$ partition $C$.

Comment: Yup. I agree, using $A\subseteq A^\circ \cup \partial A$ and $A^c \subseteq (A^c)^\circ \cup \partial A$ identity is much efficient than what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $\partial A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$ more efficiently.

Observe that $C\cap\overline{A}$ and $C\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$ are both non-empty, closed subsets of $C$.

If $$C\cap\partial A=(C\cap\overline{A})\cap (C\cap\overline{X\setminus A})=\emptyset$$ then we have a separation of $C$.

Comment: That’s what I did in approach(2). Showing $(C\cap \overline{A}) \cup (C\cap \overline{X\setminus A})=C$, require little bit of work.

Comment: @user264745 ah, i apologize i must have glossed over that part. i’ll remove this answer shortly

Comment: Please don’t remove the answer. Sometimes it happens. Your answer is a perfect/ideal hint.

Comment: @user264745 Hi, I just joined the discussion...can you please explain why $C= (C\cap \overline{A}) \cap (C\cap \overline{X \setminus A})$ requires work? i though it was trivial,  $X= A \cup X\setminus A= \overline{A} \cup \overline{X\setminus A}$ since both sets are closed and open trivially. Hence $C=X \cap C=(\overline{A} \cup \overline{X\setminus A})\cap C=C\cap \overline{A})\cap C\cap \overline{X\setminus A}$. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @J.Miller I think you’re right! It is easy to show $C=(C\cap \overline{A})\cup (C\cap \overline{X\setminus A})$. I took longer route. Your comment have a minor typo: $C=(C\cap \overline{A})\cup C\cap \overline{X\setminus A})$ instead of $C=(C\cap \overline{A})\cap (C\cap \overline{X\setminus A})$.